# Spring AOP not working when running from cmd

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-aop

I am running a Spring boot application in amazon aws, and I am using Spring AOP for logging in to a database when some annotated methods are called.

When I run my server on my local computer using IntelliJ Idea Ultimate (and not running with the gradle task!) everything is working fine, however, if I deploy it into the ElasticBeans (Java platform) or running with gradle, the top part is not working. My functions are good I see the results etc.. but nothing is logged in my database.

Can someone help, please?

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class JAspects {
private final Aspects aspectWorker;

public JAspects(@Autowired Aspects aspects) {
    this.aspectWorker = aspects;
}

@Around(value = "@annotation(enableLogging) && args(reqArg, resArg,..)")
public ResponseEntity around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, EnableLogging enableLogging, HttpServletRequest reqArg, HttpServletResponse resArg) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ResponseEntity result = null;

    try {
        result = (ResponseEntity) joinPoint.proceed();
        long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        aspectWorker.success(reqArg, resArg, result, timeTaken, enableLogging, joinPoint);
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        aspectWorker.exception(reqArg, resArg, result, timeTaken, enableLogging, joinPoint, throwable);

    }
    return result;
}}
```

and this is how i use

```
@EnableLogging(paramNames = ["firstParam", "secondParam"])
@GetMapping("api/v1/app/{mutation}&{number}/generateRedeem")
fun generateRedeemCodesForWebPage(firstParam:String, secondParam:Int){...}
```

**Additional informations**

It is working only from IntelliJ IDEA. Running the jar from commandline is the same as running it in the aws (not working aop)

Here is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
ext {
    spekVersion = "1.1.5"
    junitVersion = "4.12"
    kluentVersion = "1.25"
    pegdownVersion = "1.6.0"
    kotlinVersion = "1.2.10"
    hamkrestVersion = "1.4.2.2"
    kotlintestVersion = "2.0.7"
    apacheCommonsVersion = "3.7"
    mockitoKotlinVersion = "1.5.0"
    springBootVersion = "2.0.0.M7"
    mysqlConnectorVersion = "6.0.6"
    redmineJavaApiVersion = "3.1.0"
    junitPlatformVersion = "1.0.2"
    mainClass = "hu.click.ServerApplication"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/" }
}

dependencies {
    classpath "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:$junitPlatformVersion"
    classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlinVersion"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:$kotlinVersion"
}    }

plugins {
    id "java"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.3.RELEASE"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.2.10"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen" version "1.2.10"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa" version "1.2.10"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.noarg" version "1.2.10"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring" version "1.2.10"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "1.2.10"
    id "war"
}

apply plugin: "org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin"
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"

springBoot {
    mainClass = mainClass
}

noArg {
    annotation("hu.click.util.NoArg")
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

junitPlatform {
filters {
    engines {
        include "spek"
    }
}
}

test {
useJUnit {
    exclude '**/*IT.class'
}
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
useJUnit {
    include '**/*IT.class'
}
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest
integrationTest.mustRunAfter test

jar {
baseName = "server"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
manifest {
    attributes "Main-Class": mainClass
}
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/" }
}

dependencies {
//Spring dependencies
runtime "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
// implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop"

//Kotlin dependencies
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlinVersion"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlinVersion"

//Core dependencies
runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:$mysqlConnectorVersion"
implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:$apacheCommonsVersion"
implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.2'

// implementation "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.8"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt
//  compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.8.13'

//App dependencies
implementation "org.pegdown:pegdown:$pegdownVersion"
implementation "com.taskadapter:redmine-java-api:$redmineJavaApiVersion"

//Test dependencies
testCompile "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
testCompile "com.natpryce:hamkrest:$hamkrestVersion"
testCompile "org.amshove.kluent:kluent:$kluentVersion"
testCompile "io.kotlintest:kotlintest:$kotlintestVersion"
testCompile "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:$mockitoKotlinVersion"
testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
//these had been excluded to use the supplied kotlin version
testCompile("org.jetbrains.spek:spek-api:$spekVersion") {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin'
}
testRuntime("org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:$spekVersion") {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.platform'
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin'
}
testCompile "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:$junitPlatformVersion"
}
```

I am using gradlew bootJar, bootWar for packaging

Comment: Can you add a logger in aspect and see whether it is executed? May be there is an exception in logging to database.

Comment: I have a System.out.println("hello") inside the worker and nothing...
Also I watched the normal logs nothing related :( and every other db related function is working fine.

Comment: I would still suggest some loggers to debug the trigger and its execution.

Comment: sorry :) so additional informations: running from intellij idea aop is good and working, logs appear etc... starting from cmd with java -jar myserver.jar and everything is good except aop

Comment: Are you using maven for build with spring boot plugin for packaging?

Comment: gradle, I update the question with my gradle script one moment

Comment: Can you add aspectjweaver dependency and try?

Comment: nothing changed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see I use kotlin and java both. The problem was that I placed my java file in the src/main/kotlin directory and not in src/main/java

once I copied my java file to the right directory it began to work like charm.